# Embedded expression rendering as array instead of individual elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have the following nested components:

```
<Table data={records}>
    <TableColumn field="code">Code</TableColumn>
    {columns.map((column, i) => (
      <TableColumn key={column} field={column}>
        {column}
      </TableColumn>
    ))}
</Table>
```

My `Table` component extends this interface:

```
export interface TableProps {
  data: any[];
  children: React.ReactElement<TableColumnProps>[];
}
```

In that component, I loop through the children (instances of `TableColumn`) of the `Table` with the following function:

```
getDefaultSortColumn() {
    let col = this.props.children[0].props.field;
    this.props.children.forEach((column: React.ReactElement<TableColumnProps>) => {
      if (column.props.sortDefault) {
        col = column.props.field;
      }
    });
    return col as string;
  }
```

When this executes, my expectation is that the JSX expression with `map()` has executed and, if there are 4 items in `columns`, there will be 5 `TableColumn` elements as direct children in my `Table`.  Instead, the second element is actually an array of elements itself.

Why is my code not rendering only `TableColumn` elements as direct children to my `Table`?

**UPDATE**
It would seem that doing the following works:

```
  getDefaultSortColumn() {
    let col = this.props.children[0].props.field;
    this.props.children.forEach((child: React.ReactElement<any>) => {
      if (Array.isArray(child)) {
        child.forEach((column: React.ReactElement<O3TableColumnProps>) => {
          if (column.props.sortDefault) {
            col = column.props.field;
          }
        });
      }
      else if (child.props.sortDefault) {
        col = child.props.field;
      }
    });
    return col as string;
  }
```

But I don't want to have to access my children like this, testing whether the item is a `TableColumnProps` element type I want or an array of `TableColumnProps` elements.  The problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSX compiles down to something that looks like this:

```
const TableColumn = React.createElement('div', { field: 'code' }, 'Code')
const Table = React.createElement('div', {}, [
  TableColumn,
  columns.map((column, i) =>
    React.createElement('div', { key: column, field: column }, column),
  ),
])
```

You can see the children of `Table` include a react element, and an array of react elements. Iterating over the children array directly will give you just that.

React provides a top level api for this kind of thing -- [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) -- which traverses child arrays in your iterations with `React.Children.map` and `React.Children.forEach`.

The adjusted function would look like:

```
getDefaultSortColumn() {
  let col = this.props.children[0].props.field;
  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (column) => {
    if (column.props.sortDefault) {
      col = column.props.field;
    }
  });
  return col;
}
```

Comment: That results in the following error:  `Argument of type '(column: ReactElement<any>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(child: ReactChild, index: number) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'column' and 'child' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactChild' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'`

Comment: type checking aside, the answer is still valid and is the preferred/recommended method for looping over children in React without having to check for nested arrays. I'll update the answer to exclude the type checking bit and let you figure that part out.

See here for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jvxqvw3813

Comment: You're right.  I was able to address my type-checking and it appears to work now.  Thanks for clarifying!